# Decide Metabox Configurations for All Users

Tags: metabox

How can I decide the metabox configurations for all the users on my website? Specifically the Dashboard metaboxes I want to make a default configuration for. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metabox configuration is stored in the user meta, there are several of them so best way to find all out is to look at the ajax handlers code in \wp-admin\include\ajax-actions.php, therefor you should be able to set it up at user creation time to whatever value you want.

Comment: This is great, but is there more documentation or information on how to do this (step by step or something)?

Comment: Not that  I know of

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I will try to figure the rest out myself.